# DNS Request with Scapy over IPv6

Tags: python, dns, ipv6, scapy

I've seen many examples of how to send DNS requests via Scapy, but none for IPv6. For reference, I'm using Python 3, and `ping6 ipv6.google.com` is successful for me, so I seem to have a proper gateway. I'm trying to combine https://www.packetlevel.ch/html/scapy/scapyipv6.html and https://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-p-09-scapy-and-dns/, but I'm not sure how to do so exactly (just replacing `IP(dst=dst)` with `IPv6(dst=dst)` doesn't work). For reference, I've been trying to resolve "google.com" with Googles DNS Server (https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Edit: I wish to be able to choose the DNS server I reach. For IPv4, I could do so with the following:
`sr1(IP(dst=dns_dst)/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname=query_name)))`

Comment: May be this examples helps you https://www.packetlevel.ch/html/scapy/scapyipv6.html also is a good read https://void.gr/kargig/ipv6/scapy-IPv6_HITB06.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Yea I've found them before but not quite sure how to use the ICMP layers, which I think are related to what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- IPv6 Ping:

  ```
  sr1(IPv6(dst="www.google.com")/ICMPv6EchoRequest(),timeout=3)
  ```

That would make a simple IPv6 packet with an echo request on top, and send/receive it on level 3

- DNS over IPv6 on Google's public server, requesting an IPv6 address:

  ```
  sr1(IPv6(dst="2001:4860:4860::8888")/UDP()/DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname="www.google.com", qtype="AAAA")))
  ```

Comment: That seems to work for resolving, but to clarify, I'm looking to control which DNS server I'm using. Editing question to specify that

Comment: Sorry. I focused on the ping6 part, so I thought this was ICMP

Comment: Just saw that you edited the above. I directly copied and pasted the DNS request you put there but still receive no packets (sr1 returns None and wireshark only shows the sent packet). Since ping6 and the scapy ping you put above works for me, would you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Also I believe it should be qd, not qr

Comment: Indeed it should be

Comment: It seems to work for cloudfare's IPv6 about half the time, so I think this is it, and I have some weird stuff going on with my laptop and network. Thanks!